# Prove that $\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx = f(0)+\frac12f^\prime(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$, and assume $f^\prime$ is continuous. Prove that there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx = f(0)+\frac12f^\prime(c)$.

I tried to apply the Mean Value Theorem from which I got
\begin{align*}
f^\prime(c)& =f(1)-f(0), \\
f(c) & =\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx,
\end{align*}
both of them for some $c\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765589/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5E1_0%20f(x)%5C%2Cdx%20%3D%20f(0)%2B1%2F2*f%27(c)%24)

Comment: If you know Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder, the result follows basically immediately from that once you write down a suitable function $F(x)$.